# UITableViewCell custom cell's content resets to default values after scrolling the table view

Tags: ios, uitableview

`UITableViewCell` custom cell's contents such as `UILabel` text, `UIButton` title resets to default values(Label, Button) after Scrolling the Table View.I using number of custom cell in single table view. These is are code which i used to generate number of custom cell in single table view with different identifier and different custom cell name for each and every cell.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (customCell1 *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) cell = [[customCell1 alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
{
    NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell1" owner:self options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell = (customCell1 *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"cell2";

UITableViewCell *cell2 = (customCell2 *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

if (cell2 == nil) cell2 = [[customCell2 alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
{
    NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell2" owner:self options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell2 = (customCell2 *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}
cell.label = @"Test";
[cell2.button setTitle:@"Test Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
return cell;
return cell2;
```

Comment: Code says somethings else than you described. "i used to generate number of custom cell in single table view" - that is not in code.

Comment: paste rest of code in that function where you assign values.

Comment: I have updated my rest of code.

Comment: Have you solved it ? if yes how ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting the cell/cell2 to a UITableViewCell loaded from NIB, the reuse identifier(s) will be whatever was set in the XIB.

Anyway, the code you pasted in has quite a few issues. Is that the one you are really using? cell2 will be never returned.

Comment: I think the issue is return number of cells without passing any condition. Now i have passed condition for each cell and still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The cells in table view are dynamically created by dequeuing using the cell identifier.In the code you mentioned above will always return first "return cell";
The data source method can return only one cell at a time after the creation. So if you want to return a cell depending of your use you have to do like below

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
  //  Ideally a custom cell should be created like this

```
if(condition when you wan this cell1)
{
    //create the custom cell1 here  and return it as given below

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCustomCell";

    // Similar to UITableViewCell
    MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell1;
}
else if(when you want to create this cell2)
{
   // create the custom cell2 here  and return it
    return cell2;
}
// Create the default UI table view cell and return it . if any of the above condition did not satisfied, it will return the default cell.
```

// create default UI table here  and return it
    return cell;
}